# side job as Freelancing on highly skilled migrant visa

Tags: taxes, netherlands, freelance

I am on Highly Skilled migrant visa on Netherlands. I do freelancing on upwork along with a fulltime job. I receive freelance income in USD.

1. I want to know if the freelance income that I receive in USD can be sent  to my native country instead of Netherlands and pay the tax in native country instead of Netherlands?
2. Or do I need to pay tax in Netherlands only ?

Comment: What is 'upwork'?

Comment: @ouflak Upwork is [an online site](https://www.upwork.com) for offering and obtaining freelance work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a tax resident of the Netherlands, your worldwide income is taxable in the Netherlands, regardless of the currency in which you were paid.  You can send the money wherever you want, but it is taxable in the Netherlands regardless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have some follow up question.   1. Is it legal to do freelancing in highly skilled migrant visa 2. Is it also legal If I send income to my native country instead of netherlands ? 3. Is it fine If i pay tax in my native country and file the it return in netherlands by disclosing income and applying DTAA agreement ?

Comment: @nluser (1) I don't know; perhaps you should ask a new question; (2) I suppose so; it's your money, so you can in principle do what you want with it after you've paid your income tax, but without knowing the destination country it's not possible to say for certain; and (3) that depends entirely on the identity of your native country and the terms of the DTAA agreement.  (Is that a double taxation agreement of some sort? It probably specifies that your income is to be taxed in your place of residence with some exceptions that I expect do not include this arrangement.)